# How to locate Azure MySQL database connection string?

Tags: php, mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service

After creating a new website in Azure (Standard S1 tier), new MySQL resources were linked.

Upon entering DB's name and saving its location,  the resource with status Linked in Linked Resources tab of the web site portal becomes visible.

When navigating to the Configure tab, the connection string is not visible.

In addition to that, when going to the Dashboard tab and clicking on View Connection Strings, a message: "You have no connection strings" is displayed.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: are you building this in Visual Studios if so what version there is a bug with MySQL Database Manager and VS2013 upwards, causes all sorts of problems like the Database manager does not work correctly at all including `datasets` from a MySQL DB

Answer (score 1):

I just created a new websites and a new linked MySQL database to verify your problem.

After creating the database I can see it on the "Linked resources" tab. On the "Configure" tab I can see the connection string after that I press the "Show connection strings" link. Also, on the "Dashboard" tab I can see it when pressing the "View connection strings" link.

You can also check the connection string if you go to Kudu and check the configuration file for your site. Go to http://YOUR_SITE_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/Env#connectionStrings to see the configured connection strings.

I'm not sure what has happened if you are not able to see any configured connection strings. My guess is that something went wrong when saving the web sites settings or creating the database.

I had recently a similar situation when I created a new api app. For me, deleting and re-creating it, solved my problems.